# Parse data in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2, data-retrieval

I have a "Users" table and a "cDetails" table. Inside cDetails table I have a field called "full_name". I am trying to retrieve and output the value in this table based on the current user that is logged in.

In the cDetails table I have a field called "createdBy" which points to the objectID in the Users table that created it.

This is all I have so far:

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "cDetails")

    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    query.includeKey("full_name")
    query.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo: currentUser!.objectId!)
    print("CREATED BY  " +  PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!);
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
       (objects, error) -> Void in
        if  objects == nil {
            print(objects)
            print("called")
           // self.full_nameLabel.text = "\(query)"
        } else {
            print("FAILED")
        }
   }
```

Comment: what error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "cDetails")

let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
query.includeKey("full_name")
query.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo: currentUser!.objectId!)
print("CREATED BY  " +  PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!);
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
   (objects, error) -> Void in
    if  **objects == nil** {
        print(objects)
        print("called")
       // self.full_nameLabel.text = "\(query)"
    } else {
        print("FAILED")
    }
```

}

You are looking whether `objects == nil`. You want to have your `error == nil` and your `objects != nil`

After that proceed with

```
for object in objects {

let fullName = object["full_name"] as! String

}
```